# QT Test - Variables / Objects losing value

Tags: c++, qt, unit-testing, variables, testing

I have a QT Project `Test.pro` and want to test some classes in a few testclasses.
`Test.pro`:

```
QT       += testlib serialport
QT       -= gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

FORMS    += ../Folder/mainwindow.ui

TARGET = main
CONFIG += console
CONFIG += testcase
CONFIG -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += \
    tst_var.cpp

DEFINES += SRCDIR=\\\"$$PWD/\\\"

#LIBS += -L../libs -lserial

HEADERS += \
    tst_var.h

FORMS    +=     ../Folder/mainwindow.ui \         
                ...

QT       +=     gui
```

header file `tst_var.h`:

```
#ifndef TST_VAR_H
#define TST_VAR_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QtTest/QtTest>
#include <QString>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class tst_var: public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
     tst_var();
private  slots:
    void initTestCase();
    void testGetName();
    void cleanupTestCase();
private:
    QByteArray varname;
};

#endif // TST_VAR_H
```

The Problem is that it does not matter where I define the variable `varname` it always loses his value. `tst_var.cpp`:

```
#include "tst_var.h"

tst_var::tst_var(){
    QByteArray varname("test");
    cout << "varname1:" << varname.constData() << endl;
    //Output: test
}

void tst_var::initTestCase(){
    //It does not make a different if I would define varname here  
}

void tst_var::testGetName(){
    cout << "varname2:" << varname.constData() << endl;
   //Output: (nothing), so varname lose its content
}

void tst_var::cleanupTestCase(){}
```

I start the test via `main` method. `main.cpp`:

```
#include <QtTest/QtTest>
#include "tst_var.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    tst_var var;
    QTest::qExec(&var);
}
```

So I do not know why the variable lose its value and how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You define tst_var's constructor to be:

```
tst_var::tst_var(){
    QByteArray varname("test");
    cout << "varname1:" << varname.constData() << endl;
    //Output: test
}
```

The issue is, you define a local stack value called `varname` that is only reachable inside of the constructor function. You instead want to actually change the class's `varname` member.

Change it to be:

```
tst_var::tst_var(){
    varname = QByteArray("test");
    cout << "varname1:" << varname.constData() << endl;
    //Output: test
}
```

You can get the same issue no matter what type `varname` is and what class structure you have:

```
#include <iostream>

class tst_var {
public:
    std::string varname;
    void init() {
        std::string varname = "hey";
        std::cout<< varname <<"\n";
    }
    void test() {
        std::cout<< varname <<"\n";
    }
};

int main() {
    tst_var test;
    test.init();
    test.test();
}
```

Output:

```
hey
<empty line>
```

Fixing it with the same process fixes the issue.